# Can't Change Drives in cmder

Tags: command-line, cmder

I am unable to move to the next drives in cmder. When i put the command to move to the other drive like
    cd c:\

It again automatically moves to the Home Location.

I have searched on their official website but nothing helpful. I have find to set it up in settings but even can't find there

Answer (score 11):

Here's a [github question](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/6) that may help.

Essentially, use `Z:` to navigate to a different drive, where `Z` is the drive you want to switch to.

This is available in the latest release.

Answer (score 9):

If you are in `C` drive and want to `cd` into `D` drive then run this command

```
cd /d D:
```

if you want to `cd` into `K` drive

```
cd /d K:
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `e: & cd /a/b/c`
and use alias may save a lot of time for you 
hope this will help you 
https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/6#issuecomment-583273939

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to go `D` drive

so just put `d:` on the terminal and press enter

now you are in :)